# Incrementally counting bridges in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was trying to solve a problem on an online judge. Given an undirected graph of n vertices(<=50000), initially with no edges, we are then given m edges(<100000), and we have been asked to output the number of [bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_%28graph_theory%29) after each addition. The time limit is 2s. I know the bridge finding algorithm, which runs in O(N + M), and my straightforward O(M*(N+M)) times out predictably. Can somebody please help me with a suitable algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes i was. seems sily now. Your idea seems achievable within the time. I'll code something and get back. Thanks!!

Comment: Please share a link to the problem, I want to solve it too

Answer (score 1):

An island is a collection of nodes, such that you can traverse from one node to another without crossing any bridges. A single node not connected to any other node is an island.

An island chain is a series of islands connected by bridges. Island chains are acyclic; if you leave an island via a bridge, you cannot return to the island except by the same bridge. Note that this is not the same as saying the collection of nodes that make up the island chain is acyclic; individual islands may contain cycles.

When adding an edge to a graph, follow these rules to keep track of your chains, islands, and bridges:

1. If a new edge is added that connects an island to itself, that edge is not a bridge. The total number of bridges remain unchanged.
2. If two islands are not part of the same island chain, and a new edge is added that connects them, then that edge becomes a bridge, and the two island chains merge into a single island chain.
3. If two islands are part of an island chain, and a new edge is added that connects them, then some of the islands must be merged to uphold the acyclic property. Find the path through the island chain that connects the two islands. For all of the islands traversed in this way, including the two islands on the ends, merge all of them into a single island. Any bridges you traverse in this way cease to become bridges.

With these steps, you can keep count of the number of bridges in a graph as you add edges to them. Start with a graph of unconnected nodes. Each node is an island chain, which contains a single island, which contains a single node. As you add edges, refer to the three rules above to merge islands and island chains as necessary.

An island can be represented as a set of nodes, and an island chain can be represented as an undirected acyclic graph of islands. The most expensive part of the algorithm is finding the path between two existing islands; intuitively, I guess that the number of islands in a chain will stay small relative to `n`, so the total complexity will remain close to O(m) time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarity. I will get back to you on this after an implement.

Comment: "I guess that the number of islands in a chain will stay small relative to n" I don't think, that this is true in all cases.

Comment: In the worst case, the number of islands in a chain equals the number of nodes. However, I don't expect that to arise often, unless the judge is intentionally giving out problems that have long island chains.

Comment: You should expect worst cases when you submit code to online judge.